# ARKit - SceneView Display wrong position 3D Model

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have working on ARKit and it's my beginning. I have added 3D model to display on my ARSCNView. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-3d-object/

I'm using same car model which are available in this tutorial. When I add scene node to rootNode. The position of model not proper.

My code as follow:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    func addCar(x: Float = 0, y: Float = 0, z: Float = -0.5) {

        // Safely initialize car.dae scene
        guard let carScene = SCNScene(named: "car.dae") else { return }

        // Initialize a SCNNode object for the car node
        let carNode = SCNNode()
        let carSceneChildNodes = carScene.rootNode.childNodes

        carSceneChildNodes.forEach { carNode.addChildNode($0) }

        carNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
        carNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(carNode)
    }
```

I want to display car in proper position as display in following screenshot:

**Expected:**

[image: ARKit Expected Image]

**Output:**

[image: ARKit Output Image]

Can anyone explain what is my mistake ?? Help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed same tutorial and it's working fine. I think you have irritated your 3D model. Just delete your current **car.dae** and add new one from tutorial's project starter. Clean project and run again will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer, This one fixed my issue. :)